# Can you charge open access fees (e.g., publishing in a PLOS journal) to an NIH grant?

Tags: open-access, nih

Question is in the title. I have researched this myself and this part of the NIH FAQ seems to indicate the answer is "Yes"

https://publicaccess.nih.gov/faq.htm#810

However, I don't know exactly what is meant by "all other applicable rules on allowability of costs" means. Has anyone here ever charged open access fees (e.g., if you published in a PLOS journal) to an NIH grant or another publicly funded grant (SAMSHA, CDC, NSF, etc.)? Any info is very much appreciated.